# In Stata, how can I change the format of a date from "2010-01-11 00:00:00" to "1/11/2010"?

Tags: stata

I am currently trying to change the format of a date from "2010-01-11 00:00:00" to "01-11-2010" or "1/11/2010". Currently "2010-01-11 00:00:00" is in a string format. I have tried to coerce using the `date()` function but it never returns to the point where Stata can recognize and sort. Would anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: are you saying that the file you ingest is in the format "2010-01-11 00:00:00", as a string?

Comment: hi, yes that is correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best if for future questions you post attempted code and why it's not working for you.

Maybe this works in your case:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

set obs 1

gen dat = "2010-01-11 00:00:00"

describe
list

*----- what you want -----

gen double dat2 = clock(dat, "YDM hms")
format dat2 %tcDD-NN-YY

describe
list
```

Note that we go from string type to numeric type (double), and then adjust the display format.

See `help format`, `help datetime` and `help datetime_display_formats`.

Read also:

Stata tip 113: Changing a variable's format: What it does and does not mean
    N. J. Cox. 2012.
    Stata Journal Volume 12 Number 4. 
    http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0067

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your post, I did something a bit similar but noticed that it leaves blank values for day values past 12, like it returns values for February 1st - February 12th, but 13th to 31st, it is empty. Do you have any idea why this is the case? Thanks!

Comment: You need to be more specific. A "bit similar" is open to multiple interpretations. This is one reason you are asked to post code, results and errors, along with an explanation. You are allowed to edit your original question. I suggest you do so and add the missing, relevant, information. A minimal example reproducing your problem is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ingesting time data in  "2010-01-11 00:00:00" (SQL) format, then by default it is ingested into Stata as a str23

If you would like it as a Stata date format to manipulate, you could try the following (ingested_date_1 ... being your date columns)

```
foreach sqltime in ingested_date_1 ingested_date_2 { 
rename `sqltime' X
generate double `sqltime' =  clock(X, "YMD hms")
drop X  
format %tcDDmonCCYY_HH:MM:SS `sqltime' 
}
```

This, takes in multiple "dates", just replace your column names with ingested_date_1 ingested_date_2 etc and reformats them and keeps their 'original' name

Now the dates are in a stata recognised time format, `%tc` based of the clock, this will be sorted in the time-sense like you expect, rather than the ingested string which was not.

Additionally you may now reformat the display of the date to something that you would like or are comfortable reading, although it will make no difference to date manipulation, it is just the displayed appearance, in the case of viewing as "01-11-2010"

as Roberto says

> format ingetsed_date_i %tcDD-NN-YY

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am just curious what ingested_date_1 and ingested_date_2 represent. When I normally do the foreach command, sqltime above would represent a variable and ingested_date_1 and ingested_date_2 the limits. If I have a single column of dates in "2010-01-11 00:00:00" format named "Dates", where would "Dates" go above? thanks!

Comment: your column dates would be ingested_date_1, and delete the ingested_date_2 in the command, I just generalised it for two "date" fields

Comment: You are renaming your variables before using them. By the time you get to `generate`, Stata cannot find the variable referenced in local `sqltime`. That will generate an error.

Comment: Oops typo, need to use a dummy will change