# How can I create a trailing count for binary data in Stata?

Tags: stata

In Stata, I currently have a data set that looks like:

[image]

I am trying to create a "trailing counter" in column B so that it looks like:

[image]

Here, the counter starts at 1 and for every time a "1" appears in A, B adds on a value.

This seems to be very simple, but I am not sure how to do this exactly. Here is what I have done so far:

Assuming the column A is called "A" in Stata,

I use:

```
gen B = A + A[_n - 1]
```

But, this gives me something off. I am not sure how to proceed, would anyone have any tips?

Comment: Please don't post questions and leave them unattended. Answers merit some kind of noticeable feedback on behalf of its original poster; be that in the form of accept/upvote and/or a comment. It is not considered courteous nor good practice just to leave them hanging as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/24990010/2077064 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/24988421/2077064. See [what to do when someone answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
var1
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
end

list, sep(0)

*----- what you want -----

gen counter = sum(var1) + 1

list, sep(0)
```

The `sum()` function will give you a cumulative sum. See `help sum()`. This is a very basic Stata function. A `search sum` would have gotten you there quickly.

Your approach fails because you are only adding up, for each observation, the "current" value of `A` with the previous value of itself. That *might sound* like a cumulative sum, but think about it and you will see that it isn't.

With your code and my data, the result would be:

```
     +----------------+
     | var1   counter |
     |----------------|
  1. |    0         . |
  2. |    0         0 |
  3. |    0         0 |
  4. |    0         0 |
  5. |    1         1 |
  6. |    0         1 |
  7. |    0         0 |
  8. |    1         1 |
  9. |    0         1 |
 10. |    0         0 |
 11. |    0         0 |
     +----------------+
```

The first observation for `counter` is missing (`.`). That is because there's no previous value for the first observation of `var1`, so Stata does something like `var1[1] + var1[0] = 0 + . = .`.

The second observation for `counter` is `var1[2] + var1[1] = 0 + 0 = 0`.

The fifth observation for `counter` is `var1[5] + var1[4] = 1 + 0 = 1`.

The seventh observation for `counter` is `var1[7] + var1[6] = 0 + 0 = 0`. And so on.